# How to create a Button in half circle view in android

Tags: android

[image]

i want to create a button same as given below image. when i click on last button (last Bottom Button ) should be opened in moving state an bottom to top with half circle using animation and when i again click on button(last Bottom Button) the button should close in opposite direction.

### #  drop_down.xml#

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0.0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0.0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0.0%"
    android:toYDelta="100.0%p"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Arc Menu library](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) for your requirement

here are some of the screen shots of working model

**Arc menu**

[image]

[image]
**Ray menu**

[image]

Comment: but i am not to same view as per seem on image